# How to create jsx table from array of object dynamically?

Tags: reactjs

Using map in map to generate jsx content throws error

```
var exampleData = [
    { name: "Alex", age: 13, date: new Date()},
    { name: "Dominic", age: 313, date: new Date()},
    { name: "Fiona", age: 33, date: new Date()}
]

var tableContent = 
  <div>
    {exampleData.map((element,index) => { 
        return(
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">{index}</th> 
            {Object.keys(element).map((key)=>{ 
              return(
                <tr scope="row">{element[key]}</tr>
              )}
            }
           </tr>
        )
       })
     }
  </div>
```

React throws error : Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

In that case, sure i could just dont use second map and write code manually, but i have dozens of different kind of data to show up with a lot of keys that can change any time in development. Any advice how to do it dynamicaly?

Comment: How and where are you using the table content

Comment: I get data from my API in Json format and then i parse table headers from first element and showed tableContent is put into tbody

Comment: from that data you want to create a table where index is table header and body is the each and every key value pair in that object rit???

Comment: This is just table body content. Headers in table are my exampleData object keys and i didnt paste code of generating thead because it works well. Index is just for users to count table rows at first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.

This is what I use:

```
function toString(object) {
    if (typeof object === "string") return object;
    if (typeof object === "number") return object;
    if (typeof object === "boolean") return object ? "True" : "False";
    if (object === null || object === undefined) return "N/A";
    if (typeof object === "function") return "Function";
    if (object instanceof Date) return object.toLocaleString();
    if (object.hasOwnProperty("toString")) return object.toString();
    return JSON.stringify(object);
}

function TableView(props) {
    if (props.object.length < 1) return null;

    let keys = Object.keys(props.object[0]);

    return <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                {keys.map((key, i) => <td key={i}>{key}</td>)}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {props.object.map((row, i) => <tr key={i}>
                {keys.map((key, i) => <td key={key}>{toString(row[key])}</td>)}
            </tr>)}
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

For example:

```
let exampleData = [
    { name: "Alex", age: 13, date: new Date() },
    { name: "Dominic", age: 313, date: new Date() },
    { name: "Fiona", age: 33, date: new Date() }
]

<TableView object={exampleData} />
```

produces:

[image: Table view]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is when rendering the JS Date. In your example data you create a date by using `new Date()` which indeed returns a JS Date Object. In order to render the date just convert it to a string format.

```
const tableContent = 
  <div>
    {exampleData.map((element,index) => { 
        return(
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">{index}</th> 
            {Object.keys(element).map((key)=>{
              const el = element[key]
              return(<tr scope="row">{el instanceof Date ? el.toUTCString() : el}</tr>)
             }
            }
           </tr>
        )
       })
     }
  </div>
```

You may also want to check how you're formatting your table. Here's a working fiddle: [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/1q8naLx5/)